# stacking divs in columns

Tags: html, css

I have a three column layout where I float the left column left, float the middle column left and the right column I float right.  I am not sure if this a good way of laying the page out, but it has worked in the past.  What I would like to do now though is giving me trouble. I want to stack a couple of divs in the center and right columns, but I can't seem to make it happen.

So instead of the center column being one column from top to bottom of the page I now want the center column to be two panels, one stacked above the other, not overlapping. Overlapping I seem to have no problem with ;)

Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what exactly you are trying to do. Any chance you could upload an image where you draw your desired outcome?

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already checked out [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) Apart you should, as it contains some excellent tutorials and guidelines for website design.

[THis article](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)  in particular should help you out.

### Css

```
body {
  min-width: 630px;      /* 2x (LC fullwidth +
                            CC padding) + RC fullwidth */
}
#container {
  padding-left: 200px;   /* LC fullwidth */
  padding-right: 190px;  /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
}
#container .column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#center {
  padding: 10px 20px;    /* CC padding */
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 180px;          /* LC width */
  padding: 0 10px;       /* LC padding */
  right: 240px;          /* LC fullwidth + CC padding */
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#right {
  width: 130px;          /* RC width */
  padding: 0 10px;       /* RC padding */
  margin-right: -190px;  /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
}/*** IE Fix ***/
* html #left {
  left: 150px;           /* RC fullwidth */
}
```

### Html

```
<div id="header"></div><div id="container">
  <div id="center" class="column"></div>
  <div id="left" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right" class="column"></div>
</div><div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: if this is what you were looking for accept it as answer or upvote it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of your both of your middle divs to 50%. The width of each column div should be 33%.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middleColumn">
        <div id="middleTop"></div>
        <div id="middleBottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{height:300px;width:300px;}
#left,#middleColumn,#right{height:100%;width:33.33%;float:left;}
#middleTop,#middleBottom{height:50%;width:100%;}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle describing what I'm saying.](http://jsfiddle.net/LT54R/)

Comment: Thanks. You know, I have cross browser problems with dynamic div sizing. If I set all of my columns at 33%, the one on the right get squeezed down.  I end up making one of the columns 30% to work around this issue.  It is especially a problem when the browser window is not maximized. Obviously 33% works for you, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked padding?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do for this situation:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar-right"></div>
        <div class="content top"></div>
        <div class="content bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; } // Whatever width you want
.main { width: 75%; float: right; }
.sidebar-left { width: 25%; float: left; }
.sidebar-right { width: 25%; float: right; }
.content { width: 50%; float: left; clear: left; }
```

This will give you something like this:

[image: format for layout]

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5j5z/) that you can play with. I added some color and heights so you can see whats going happening with the CSS. You may want to also look into a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) for the wrapper `div` so that you don't have issues with positioning.

Comment: Thanks yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do.